# Boxplots in matplotlib - Making room for the text

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the picture below, I am following the approach described in this thread: [Overlaying the numeric value of median/variance in boxplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861075/overlaying-the-numeric-value-of-median-variance-in-boxplots)

How can I control the bounding box or size of the boxes in the boxplot so that the text doesn't overflow the figure or collides with adjacent boxes?

[image]

Comment: tight_layout might be able to help you out.  In general, automatically laying out text is a weakness of matplotlib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the figure extent by calling figure with the figsize argument:

```
figure(figsize=(xsize,ysize))
```

You could alternatively reduce the font size (generally not ideal) through use of the size argument:

```
text(x, y, '%.1f' % x,
     horizontalalignment='center', size=size)
```