# matplotlib box and whisker underlying stats

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics

I have created box and whisker plots using matplotlib.  My question is how to ensure that the calculated statistics which appear in the chart match those I would calculate via a built-in function like .mean() of a column.  From what I can tell, if outliers are found then the 75, 50, 25 quartiles will reflect this (calculated without outliers) and will therefore not match statistics inclusive of outliers.  My guess is that if I do a 1.5 IQR filter and then run my stats such as .mean() they will match.  Any way to directly peak at the stats being used by the matplotlib box-whisker plot?  Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation for `boxplot`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot)? Are any of the return values what you need for a comparison? Did you look at all the optional parameters and their default values? `whis` looks interesting.

Comment: It looks like you can do a returnDict = boxplot(inputData) and then parse out what you want.  Looks like you are getting the dimensions of the lines used to draw the plots.  This seems messy but maybe the only way.

Comment: Is there a better way then this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861075/overlaying-the-numeric-value-of-median-variance-in-boxplots/18861734#18861734

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the function that `boxplot` uses to calculate the data.

I have always had good luck looking and searching through the [Matplotlib source](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib) to find how it does stuff.  [`boxplot`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L3141) uses the function [matplotlib.cbook.boxplot_stats](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/abe0e3957596c1f455a2f84b97731651f1e5b9cf/lib/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py#L1142) to do the calcs.  You can call this function yourself and inspect the returned data:

```
from matplotlib import cbook
print(help(cbook.boxplot_stats))
data = cbook.boxplot_stats(values)
```

From the `boxplot_stats` docstring:

```
Returns
-------
bxpstats : list of dict
    A list of dictionaries containing the results for each column
    of data. Keys of each dictionary are the following:

    ========   ===================================
    Key        Value Description
    ========   ===================================
    label      tick label for the boxplot
    mean       arithemetic mean value
    med        50th percentile
    q1         first quartile (25th percentile)
    q3         third quartile (75th percentile)
    cilo       lower notch around the median
    cihi       upper notch around the median
    whislo     end of the lower whisker
    whishi     end of the upper whisker
    fliers     outliers
    ========   ===================================
```

---

Source links are for the current *master* on this date. Current Matplotlib version is 2.2.2