# display median value on matplotlib boxplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, data-visualization, boxplot

I am creating a boxplot using matplotlib package. On one graph, I am showing 15 boxplots side by side. By the median mark on each boxplot, I would like text to display the numerical value of the median. How can I do this?

Here is my code, which currently displays the 15 boxplots side by side without the numerical value of the medians shown:

** Note cancer_data is a list of 15 tuples

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
testPlot = ax.boxplot(cancer_data, showfliers=False)

plt.xticks(y_pos, cancer_types)

ax.set_title("Title", y=1.05)
ax.set_ylabel("Y-Var", labelpad=10)
ax.set_xlabel("X-Var", labelpad=10)

ax.legend()

for tick in ax.get_xticklabels():
    tick.set_rotation(90)

plt.xticks(np.arange(1, 16))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 6, 0.5))


plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: i would use `Axes.annotate` and `Axes.text`. https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#text-and-annotations

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overlaying the numeric value of median/variance in boxplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861075/overlaying-the-numeric-value-of-median-variance-in-boxplots)