# How to display numeric mean and std values next to a box plot in a series of box plots?

Tags: python, pandas, text, label, boxplot

I'm trying to display the value of mean and standard deviation next to my box plots in a plot of multiple box plots. Nothing is displayed when I try.

```
#Boxplot 3

data3 =np.array([[ 4.38,  3.27,  6.07],
   [ 4.35,  3.51,  6.14],
   [ 4.09,  3.33,  5.92],
   [ 4.9 ,  3.97,  5.02],
   [ 4.56,  3.5 ,  4.5 ],
   [ 4.78,  3.95,  4.58]])

fig3 = plt.figure(3)

ax3 = fig3.add_subplot(111)
ax3.boxplot(data3, showmeans=True)

ax3.set_title('Serve - Data Location and Variance 1',fontsize=15,fontweight='bold', y=1.06)
ax3.set_ylabel('Velocity [m/s]',fontsize=11.5)
ax3.set_xlabel('Parameter',fontsize=11.5)
ax3.set_xticklabels(['V_in', 'V_out', 'V_bat'],style='italic')
ax3.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()
ax3.get_yaxis().tick_left()


m1=data3.mean(axis=0) #Mean values 
mL1 = [str(np.round(s, 2)) for s in m1]

st1=data3.std(axis=0) #Standard deviation values 
sT1=[str(np.round(s, 2)) for s in st1]

ind=0
for i in range (len(ax3.get_xticklabels())):
ax3.text(i, m1[ind]+1, mL1[ind], horizontalalignment='center',  color='w', weight='semibold')
ind+=1
```

The last four lines need to be corrected as the other code is working fine (see picture) [image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `boxplot` method returns a dictionary that includes parts of the boxplot (whiskers, caps, boxes, medians, fliers, means). You can use these to add annotation at various location within the plot. Below I added mean and standard deviation values to the right of the median line:

Read this for more details [Overlaying the numeric value of median/variance in boxplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861075/overlaying-the-numeric-value-of-median-variance-in-boxplots)

```
m1 = data3.mean(axis=0)
st1 = data3.std(axis=0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bp = ax.boxplot(data3, showmeans=True)

for i, line in enumerate(bp['medians']):
    x, y = line.get_xydata()[1]
    text = ' μ={:.2f}\n σ={:.2f}'.format(m1[i], st1[i])
    ax.annotate(text, xy=(x, y))
```

which plots

[image]

Comment: Thanks! However, instead of displaying greek letters my plot shows small rectangles (as if it can't show the greek letters). Any idea to solve this?

Comment: What is the version of your Matplotlib library? I think after version 2.0, the default font supports math characters, Greek letters, etc.

Comment: I had an old version, so I updated Python and all the packages. Now it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @stahamtan - can you also help with this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58268651/display-mean-and-deviation-values-on-grouped-boxplot-in-python?noredirect=1#comment102927803_58268651]?

Comment: Thanks a bunch, saved me a lot of timel!