# Labelling group boxplot in seaborn with mean and standard deviation values

Tags: python, label, seaborn, boxplot, annotate

How can I label each boxplot in a seaborn grouped boxplot with the mean and standard deviation value?

[image]

My code is

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from os.path import expanduser as ospath

df = pd.read_excel(ospath('~/Documents/Python/Kandidatspeciale/TestData.xlsx'),'Ark1')

bp = sns.boxplot(y='throw angle', x='incident angle', 
                 data=df, 
                 palette="colorblind",
                 hue='Bat type')

bp.set_title('Rubber Comparison',fontsize=15,fontweight='bold', y=1.06)
bp.set_ylabel('Throw Angle [degrees]',fontsize=11.5)
bp.set_xlabel('Incident Angle [degrees]',fontsize=11.5)
```

Where my dataframe, df, is

```
     Bat type  incident angle  throw angle
0      euro              15         28.2
1      euro              15         27.5
2      euro              15         26.2
3      euro              15         27.7
4      euro              15         26.4
5      euro              15         29.0
6      euro              30         12.5
7      euro              30         14.7
8      euro              30         10.2
9     china              15         29.9
10    china              15         31.1
11    china              15         24.9
12    china              15         27.5
13    china              15         31.2
14    china              15         24.4
15    china              30          9.7
16    china              30          9.1
17    china              30          9.5
```

Comment: very similar to previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58268651/1358308 note that from a "statistical graphics" point of view putting these summary stats on a plot is generally considered bad practice. see e.g. http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/vis14.pdf

Comment: It is similar to the previous question. I reposted it because no one could give me a solution :-) @SamMason

Comment: @MatiMalik I answered the first post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58268651/display-mean-and-deviation-values-on-grouped-boxplot-in-python/67118484#67118484)